# Commands are written down instead of being executed in Dragon NaturallySpeaking

Tags: windows-7, dragon-naturally-speaking

From time to time commands are written down instead of being executed in Dragon NaturallySpeaking. What can account for this issue?

Examples:

- when I say the built-in command "Backspace", instead of pressing the key  <kbd>BACK</kbd> Dragon will write "Backspace"
- when I say my custom command "dictation", instead of executing my code Dragon will write "start dictation box"

Note that when the issue appears, not all voice commenced are affected. E.g. the command "Copy that" keep working.

The custom command "dictation" is the following:

```
Sub Main
    HeardWord "start", "dictation", "box"
End Sub
```

I use Dragon NaturallySpeaking 12.5 Professional with Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.

I use the *Normal mode*:

[image]

---

Demo: http://youtu.be/8KGXeV9RjOY

[image]